# Whence /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, dpkg

Where does the /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini file come from on Ubuntu 16.04?

```
dpkg -S /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

returns nothing.

```
dpkg -S /etc/php/7.0/apache2/
```

shows that the directory is installed by the libapache2-mod-php7.0 package, but

```
dpkg-query -L libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

does not mention "php.ini". I'm guessing that this file is copied during a postinstall process. Is there a way to determine which package installation is creating this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are searching for the how something got on your system often you might just want to try a command like this `grep 'php.ini' /var/lib/dpkg/info/*`.  The `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` contains files related to packages, which include the `packagename.list` which is used by the dpkg -S, the `packagename.conffiles` which is a list of the conffiles, and the files for the various pre/post install/remove scripts like `packagename.actionname`.

```
# grep 'php.ini' /var/lib/dpkg/info/*

/var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php7.0.postinst:    phpini="/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini"
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php7.0.postinst:  ucf /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production.apache2 $phpini
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php7.0.postinst:  ucf /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production $phpini
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php7.0.postrm:    phpini=/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/var/lib/dpkg/info/php7.0-cli.postinst:    phpini="/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini"
...

# cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php7.0.postinst
...
if [ "$1" = "configure" ]; then
    phpini="/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini"

    if [ "apache2" = "cli" ]; then
    ucf /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production.apache2 $phpini
    else
    ucf /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production $phpini
    fi
    ucfr libapache2-mod-php7.0 $phpini
...
```

Anyway for this particular query we see that the php.ini is being added via [ucf](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/ucf/ucf.1.en.html) from `/usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production`.  UCF is one of a few tools that can be used by Debian packages to maintain configuration files.  UCF can accept some values from users to be merged in, it can detect and auto-update or merge configurations in some situations and so on.